# Rust alloc memory layout not consistent with size

Tags: memory-management, rust

I must be misunderstanding something here but I wrote a simple piece of code to test memory addresses and am getting some strange results:

Here is the code:

use std::alloc::{alloc, Layout};

```
fn main() {
    let r1 : *mut i32;
    let r2 : *mut i32;
    let r3 : *mut i32;
    let r4 : *mut u8; 
    let r5 : *mut i32;
    unsafe { 
        r1 = alloc(Layout::new::<i32>()) as *mut i32;
        r2 = alloc(Layout::new::<i32>()) as *mut i32;
        r3 = alloc(Layout::new::<i32>()) as *mut i32;
        r4 = alloc(Layout::new::<i8>()); 
        r5 = alloc(Layout::new::<i32>()) as *mut i32;
    }   
    println!("Raw pointer r1: {:p}", r1);
    println!("Raw pointer r2: {:p}", r2);
    println!("Raw pointer r3: {:p}", r3);
    println!("Raw pointer r4: {:p}", r4);
    println!("Raw pointer r5: {:p}", r5);
}
```

and when I run it I get:

```
Raw pointer r1: 0x7fdb17402a60
Raw pointer r2: 0x7fdb17402a70
Raw pointer r3: 0x7fdb17402a80
Raw pointer r4: 0x7fdb17402a90
Raw pointer r5: 0x7fdb17402aa0
```

Two questions:

1. I see that according to the docs i32s take up 4 bytes, so why is the address space difference between r1 and r2 0x10 instead of 0x04? Same question for cases between r4 and r5 where I expected only a 1 byte offset.
2. Why is *mut 8, which is what `alloc` returns, sufficient as a pointer? We would not be able to represent the 64 bit virtual memory addresses using just a byte right?

I'm trying to learn these unsafe aspects of rust because there I will be working on some kernel related project and it is necessary to work with raw pointers.

Comment: A `*mut u8` does not occupy a single byte ...

Answer (score 2):

This question is not rust specific but rather a question regarding how memory allocation works.  Memory allocators need to:

- consider the alignment requirements of the underlying architecture ... for example, the returned pointer may wish to be divisible by the processor word size;
- store the size of the allocated space (for de-allocation purposes)

Thus consider allocating a single 32-bit integer ... the allocator will wish to allocate space to store:

1. a word for storing the size of the space allocated;
2. the 32-bit integer (which takes half a word in this case)

As allocation wishes to be word aligned, the next allocation will occur two words, or 16 bytes, after the first.

As to your second question, a `* mut u8` does not occupy a single byte, as surely the value the given code printed for it demonstrates.